# Large zip downloads failing only in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http-headers

I have a little script which sets the header to force download of a zip file with:

```
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
         ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        }
    header("Pragma: public");
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$mp3.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".@filesize($file));
    @readfile($file) OR die("<html>...</html>");
    exit;
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but fails in IE 9.  I have tried many different ways of setting those headers after googling around but nothing helps.  Then I tried a different smaller zip file and it worked!  Then I tried a bigger zip file and again fail.  Would this be some setting on the server or the php.ini or something?  Why does it only affect IE?

When it fails in IE it looks like it downloads.. says completed.  But the file is 0 bytes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: IE always downloads the file to its cache first and then copy it to the final destination. I wonder if IE isn't removing the file from the cache immediately upon completion, since it would have expired already.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is large enough you may have issues related to memory, execution time, etc.

Instead of trying to read the file, you could use the x-sendfile header:

```
header('x-sendfile: '.$file);
```

Check out this article about it: http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Comment: I was thinking that but I dont understand why a memory issue would be browser related.. and the file isnt really that big (80,000 kb).  I updated my post to explain how IE fails.. it actually acts like everything is ok but it is a 0kb file.  Thanks for providing the alternative but I dont think I have access to change apache on this server and it didnt fix anything after I just slapped x-sendfile in there.

Comment: yeah, it's a tricky one. Try using a http proxy like charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Check the headers for IE vs other browsers to see if there's any difference. it could be your server is handling IE requests differently?

Comment: ahh i figured it out.. I had the path to the file wrong :-/   The other browsers let it slide but IE needed an absolute path.